# How to update choropleth map in Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm making a webapp using Python and Dash, this webapp includes a choropleth map of the world with data based on the selected year. I want to be able to change the year and with that also update the map to match that year. I prefer to do this with the Dash slider, although any other way I would appreciate as well.

I've tried updating other graphs such as line charts with the text input, and that worked, but when i changed it to a choropleth map it stopped updating. It now only creates the map but updates on it don't show up. I've put some print text in the update function and it confirmed that it is actually called when I change the input, but the graph just doesn't update.

### The layout:with the dcc.input i want to update the html.Div 'my-div'

```
app.layout = html.Div( children=[
    html.H1(
        children='UN Sustainable Development goal: Poverty',
        style={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'color': colors
        }
    ),
    dcc.Input(id='my-id',value='30', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
    ,
    daq.Slider(
        id='my-daq-slider',
        min=1,
        max=sliderlength,
        step=1,
    ),
    html.Div(id='slider-output')

    

    
],        style={
        'textAlign': 'center'
    })
```

### The update part

```
@app.callback(
    Output('my-div', 'children'),
    [Input('my-id', 'value')])

def update_output_div(input_value):
    return dcc.Graph(
        id='my-div',

        figure={'data': [go.Choropleth(
    locations = df_pov['Country Code'],
    z = df_pov.iloc[:,int(input_value)],
    text = df_pov['Country Name'],
    
    autocolorscale = True,
    reversescale = False,
    marker = go.choropleth.Marker(
        line = go.choropleth.marker.Line(
            color = 'rgb(180,180,180)',
            width = 0.5
        )),
    colorbar = go.choropleth.ColorBar(
        tickprefix = '%',
        title = '%  below 1.90$ '),
)],
                'layout': go.Layout(
    title = go.layout.Title(
        text = list(df_pov)[int(input_value)]
    ),
    geo = go.layout.Geo(
        showframe = False,
        showcoastlines = False,
        projection = go.layout.geo.Projection(
            type = 'equirectangular'
        )
    ),
    annotations = [go.layout.Annotation(
        x = 0.55,
        y = 0.1,
        xref = 'paper',
        yref = 'paper',
        text = 'Source: Kaggle',
        showarrow = False
    )]
)            
        }
    )
```

What i expected: for the choropleth to update when changing the text input, or slider input.
Actual: the map gets created once ( with the same function that should update it), but doesn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash doesn't like new components being loaded in like this. Try initializing your graph by adding an empty graph to the layout like this:

```py
html.Div(id='my-div', children=[
        dcc.Graph(
            id='my-graph-id',
            figure=dict(
                data=[],
                layout={},
            ),
        )
    ])
```

With the graph already on the page, you would have to change the callback so that it updates the `figure` prop of the `Graph` instead of the `children` of the `div`.

Also, you have multiple IDs that are the same. Dash doesn't like that. Make sure every ID is unique. If all of this still does not work, I may need to ask you to post some more details so I can help further. Good luck!